# How do I resolve? Module not found: Can't resolve '../styles.globals.scss' VsCode

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, ant-design-pro

This is the error message I am getting with my import statement for the scss file in my _app.tsx. How do I resolve this? I am using Next.js & I've tried almost everything on the web
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNrjx.png

Comment: Please share more details like package.json dependencies, next-config.js . I am thinking CSS loaders(postCss-loader, sass) are not installed. please check that.

Answer (score 2):

You made a directory with the name of style and inside that you made globals.scss and you tried to use it with ../styles.globals.scss

You have to use ../styles/globals.scss